# NLP : Find word position in string if I have only character position

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp

I have a dataframe with 2 columns: `text,char_position`, with the first column having a sentence and the second column has position of the starting character of a specific word. For example :

```
text                       char_position
This is an example sentence.   11
```

Here the `char_position` appends to the starting character of the word *example*.

My question is : Is there a way to create a new column named `word_position` and have the position of the word that the `char_position` mentions? I.e. in this example it would be  `word_position  = 3`.

Comment: please provide a more minimal example (just a few words) as DataFrame constructor

Answer (score 0):

counting the spaces would work:

```
text = "This is an example sentence."
char_pos = 11;

word_position = 0;
for i in range(char_pos):
    if text[i].isspace():
        word_position += 1;
        
print(word_position)
```

output:

```
3
```

you have to test all the edge cases yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Using a custom function and a list comprehension:

```
import re
def get_word(string, pos):
    for i, m in enumerate(re.finditer('\w+', string)):
        if m.end()>=pos:
            return i
            # to get the word use
            # return m.group()
            
df['word_position'] = [get_word(t, p) for t, p in
                       zip(df['text'], df['char_position'])]
```

output:

```
                           text  char_position  word_position
0  This is an example sentence.             11              3
```